# Three.js + Theatre.js Moving all keyframes

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm using the fantastic Theatre.js[1] library to animate part of my website.

Now want to go back and add some animation at the beginning.

In the Sequence Editor, I can't seem to select all points / keyframes and move them using the studio UI.

Am I going to have to manually move every part of the animation over?

The position of the keyframes relative to each other is more of an art than a science, and it'll probably mess up the work I've done so far.

Is there a bit of javascript that I could paste into the console that would simply loop through all the points and shunt them to the right, by a fixed amount of time?

[1] https://www.theatrejs.com/docs/latest/manual/Studio#sequence-editor